# Send ticket id to client when user creates an issue in redmine

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine

New Requirement:Want to send email containing only the ticket id of the issue newly created to the client who raised the issue.How can I proceed with this requirement?Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I am currently working on this new plugin for Redmine: https://github.com/nanego/redmine_unregistered_watchers. Maybe it will help you when it will be finished. As a temporary fix, you could update these files (app/mailer/issue_add.html.erb and app/mailer/issue_add.text.erb) and remove unnecessary data.

Comment: Should i cut everything wat is there in app/mailer/issue_add.text.erb and paste <%email content%> there??And wat about the app/models/mailer folder??

Comment: Yes, if you only want to change the content of the emails, you can simply edit files in the 'views' folder.

Comment: Should I copy other files to my redmine folders?I mean from app/models and app/controllers??

Comment: Oops, I just realized you were talking about my plugin files. Actually, for a quick fix, you could directly modify Redmine core files. It's better to use plugins, but mine is not finished yet.

Comment: You can also contribute to the new plugin and list in Github which feature you would like to add.

Comment: May I know when will you finish your plugins so that i can directly install the same?

Comment: M new to redmine and ruby on rails..Please suggest me wat can i do?Its required urgently

Comment: plugin watever u implementing will only send the issue status or wat??i need only to send the ticket ID to the client wen issue is created.Can it be done??

Comment: Hello,what about the plugin?Did you finish it?/

Comment: Yes, the current version of the plugin allows you to send a custom email to specific addresses each time a ticket is created (or any other status change). You specify the recipients (the unregistered watchers) when you create or edit the issue.

Comment: So the plugin is ready for installation right.I will install the plugin.??Can I use this plugin for sms too??

Comment: Not at all, but it's a good idea.

Comment: When you will finish that plugin??

Comment: It currently works well for my needs.

Comment: which redmine version are you using??Do you know any plugin which sends sms to client when we select thier number from custom field?

Comment: I have tested it with Redmine 2.6

Comment: I tried in redmine-2.6.While running rake command I got error..